# Derby get CLOB with open db connection fails

Tags: java, derby, clob

I have a CLOB field in a derby table. After a simple SQL SELECT I try to convert CLOBs into Strings.

- DBConnection autocommit is off
- DBConnection is open
- This code fails although I never call the free() method:

dbCon.connect;

```
  dbSourceDataList = dbCon.executeQuery(getSql());

   // convert all CLOBs to Strings      
  for (int i = 0; i < dbSourceDataList.size(); i++) {
    Object[] arr = dbSourceDataList.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[j] instanceof Clob) {
        Clob clob = (Clob) arr[j]; 
        arr[j] = clob.getSubString(1, (int) clob.length());
      }
    }
  }
```

No java.sql.Clob/java.sql.Blob methods can be called after free() method has been called or a blob/clob transactions has been commited or rollbacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert CLOBs to Strings using *directly* the getClob() method of the java.sql.ResultSet:

```
if (rs.getObject(i) instanceof java.sql.Clob) {
   // Convert CLOBs to Strings
   Clob clob = rs.getClob(i);
   stringValue = clob.getSubString(1, (int) clob.length());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JDBC BLOB/CLOB programming is quite complex. You can find some good information about the way Derby implements BLOB/CLOB data types here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefjdbc96386.html

Another good resource is to look in the Derby source tree, at the Derby regression test suite; there are many good examples of BLOB/CLOB programming in the test suites.